# Is possible to communicate the components which is running on different server by OSGI

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, osgi

We are going to develop large scale application by using J2EE. The application has contains many number of modules. For the purpose we have planned to split the application into module application and run it on different servers.

If i use OSGI, then is it possible to communicate between the two module component which is running on different server?

I am not familiar in OSGI. Please help me to find the solution for the large scale application

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start from the OSGi Remote Services Specification. Apache CXF project provides an implementation for that. Quoting [from CXF web page](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html):

> It implements the Remote Services functionality using Web Services, leveraging SOAP over HTTP and exposing the Service over a WSDL contract.

In my experience, embedding CXF in Equinox (the Eclipse OSGi implementation) has been very easy.

However DOSGI is not the only way to go: queueing systems like JMS or distributed caches like Hazelcast can help you to distribute events and data across the system. These technologies can be easily embedded in OSGi as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's another one ;)
If run with Apache Karaf you just need to install the Apache Karaf sub-project Cellar and it's corresponding DOSGi feature. With those two, you'll have 1) a clustering solution for Karaf and 2) a way for your Applications to communicate with different cluster-groups. All of this comes out-of-the-box with Karaf 3, just install the extra features cellar and cellar-dosgi :)

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation of the Remote Services specification is Amdatu Remote:

https://amdatu.atlassian.net/wiki/display/AMDATUDEV/Amdatu+Remote

The Amdatu Remote subproject provides implementations of the OSGi Remote Services 1.0 (OSGi Enterprise R5) and Remote Service Admin 1.1 (under development) specifications.